# Getting an error on openCV android: CameraActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed

Tags: java, android, opencv

I want to do image processing on frames from Android Camera in real time with OpenCv, but i am getting Error 'Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!' Can anyone provide any assistance.
I guess it could be memory leaks somewhere.
This is my code:

```
 public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        mGray = inputFrame.gray();
        Imgproc.equalizeHist(mGray, mGray);
        MatOfRect signs = new MatOfRect();
        listSign = new ArrayList<Sign>();

        detector.Detect(mGray, signs, 2);
        Rect[] dangerArray = signs.toArray();
        detector.Detect(mGray, signs, 1);
        Rect[] prohibitionArray = signs.toArray();

        if ((prohibitionArray.length > 0) && (dangerArray.length > 0)) {
            Rect[] matArray = Arrays.copyOf(dangerArray, (dangerArray.length + prohibitionArray.length));
            System.arraycopy(prohibitionArray, 0, matArray, dangerArray.length, prohibitionArray.length);
            Draw(matArray);
        } else if (prohibitionArray.length > 0){
            Draw(prohibitionArray);
        } else if (dangerArray.length > 0){
            Draw(dangerArray);
        }
        return mRgba;
    }

    public void Draw(Rect[] facesArray) {
        if (facesArray.length <= 0) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    listRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

        } else for (int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++) {
            final int ii = i;
            Mat subMat = new Mat();
            subMat = mRgba.submat(facesArray[i]);
            Sign.myMap.put("Hinh" + i, Utilities.convertMatToBitmap(subMat));
            sp.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba, facesArray[i].tl(), facesArray[i].br(), FACE_RECT_COLOR, 2);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Sign sign = new Sign("unknown", "Hinh" + ii);
                    listSign.add(sign);
                    listRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    itemAdapter adapter = new itemAdapter(listSign, CameraActivity.this);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    listDetectedSigns.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any progress on this?